# how to read city ,state,country from google map geocoding json data

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I'm using .net MVC 3 and Google Maps v3. I'd like to do geocoding in an action. That is passing a valid address to Google and getting the city,state and country back. How would you do this in an action using C#?

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult getLocation(string pincode)
    {
        string url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?
         sensor=true&address=";
        var data="";
        dynamic googleResults = new Uri(url + 
         pincode).GetDynamicJsonObject();
        foreach (var result in googleResults.results)
        {

            data= "[" + result.geometry.location.lat + "," + 
         result.geometry.location.lng + "] " + result.formatted_address;
        }
        return Json("Successful" + data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

this is json data which i am getting from google geocoding from which i wants to read city,state and country from address_components types administrative_area_level_2,administrative_area_level_1,country

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "411022",
               "short_name" : "411022",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "SRPF",
               "short_name" : "SRPF",
               "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_2" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Wanowrie",
               "short_name" : "Wanowrie",
               "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Pune",
               "short_name" : "Pune",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Pune",
               "short_name" : "Pune",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Maharashtra",
               "short_name" : "MH",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "SRPF, Wanowrie, Pune, Maharashtra 411022, India",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 18.5065017,
                  "lng" : 73.9128001
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 18.4966367,
                  "lng" : 73.90290019999999
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 18.4986371,
               "lng" : 73.9074389
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 18.5065017,
                  "lng" : 73.9128001
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 18.4966367,
                  "lng" : 73.90290019999999
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJQ1UppdzBwjsRPIND-6yqBNI",
         "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: Why the `foreach` if you only set a singular `data` variable? Why prepend this string `return Json("Successful" + data,` which likely creates invalid results?

Comment: because i want this data to be return in ajax success method

Comment: Why not just `return Json(googleResults, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`?  You could then get that JSON string and process it client side.

Comment: yes i can do that way also, but its same thing whether i process data at server side and then send it or first send data at client side and then process it

Comment: my question is how to read city,state and country separately rather than reading formatted address

Comment: Those are in the `address_components` broken  out as you see in your results.  Just pick those out from that portion?  What am i not understanding here?

Comment: Specifically `return Json(googleResults.results.address_components., JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` then use that client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I solved this problem by sending json data to client side like this
 var data = "";
            dynamic googleResults = new Uri(url + pincode).GetDynamicJsonObject();
            var status = googleResults.status;
            foreach (var result in googleResults.results)
            {
                              data += result;
            }
            return Json(data, "application/json",Encoding.UTF8, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


and then process this data in javascript ,code given below

 data = JSON.parse(result);

                for(var i=0;i<data.address_components.length;i++)
                {

                    if(data.address_components[i].types[0]=="administrative_area_level_2")
                    {
                        alert("City:" + data.address_components[i].long_name);
                        document.getElementById("pin_city").value = data.address_components[i].long_name;
                    }
                    if (data.address_components[i].types[0] == "administrative_area_level_1") {
                        alert("State:" + data.address_components[i].long_name);
                        document.getElementById("pin_state").value = data.address_components[i].long_name;
                    }
                    if (data.address_components[i].types[0] == "country") {
                        alert("Country:" + data.address_components[i].long_name);
                    }

                }
```

Comment: Thank You @Mark Schultheiss for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
data=["address_components"]["type"]["administrative_level_2"][your value]
data2=["address_components"]["type"]["administrative_level_1"][your value]
```

you can also used like this

```
data=["result"]["address_components"]["type"]["administrative_level_2"][your value];
data2=["result"]["address_components"]["type"]["administrative_level_1"][your value];
```

result is 1st array of json