# Accessing State Information from Zip Code Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am able to get the state from the google maps api (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode) when a user enters a zip code. But, for some reason the location of the state information changes depending on the zip code.

The only solution I can think of is querying both possible locations and storing them in a variable and checking for the state but it doesn't seem very practical.

```
//sometimes it's located in this area (the state short name like CA)
$thestate['results'][0]['address_components'][4]['short_name'];

//other times it's located here

$thestate['results'][0]['address_components'][3]['short_name'];
```

Any idea how I can accurately pick the state short_name every time? It seems odd that they would move the location, and I'm trying to accurately pull that out.

Comment: You need to look at the address types each address_component to determine which entry in the array will contain the state.

Comment: related question: [how to read city ,state,country from google map geocoding json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43231182/how-to-read-city-state-country-from-google-map-geocoding-json-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to locate the `address_components` entry which has the type `administrative_area_level_1`.

> administrative_area_level_1 indicates a first-order civil entity below
>   the country level. Within the United States, these administrative
>   levels are states. Not all nations exhibit these administrative
>   levels. In most cases, administrative_area_level_1 short names will
>   closely match ISO 3166-2 subdivisions and other widely circulated
>   lists; however this is not guaranteed as our geocoding results are
>   based on a variety of signals and location data.

From [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro)